# Css and php layout issues

Tags: php, css

I am using a table coded through php to form two column results with an xml feed, the columns form ok, the problem is that the second column gets cut off.

example here:  http://www.qrrw.net/b

my css

```
td.manu {
    background: url("../images/manu_button.fw.png") no-repeat; 
    height: 87px; 
    width:478;  
    font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    color:#309;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

When i use the chrome web developer plugin it shows that the second column has a different width, but it is using the same class.

below is my **PHP-Code**:

```
$count = 0;
$max = 2;
foreach($xml->name as $name){               
    $count++;
    echo '<td class="manu">'. $name['name'];'</td>';

    if($count >= $max){
        //reset counter
        $count = 0;
        //end and restart
        echo '</tr><tr>';
    }
}
?>
```

final HTML

```
  <table border=0 width="800px">
  <tr>
  <td class="manu">3000 ME</td><td class="manu">Ace</td></tr><tr><td class="manu">Cobra MK IV</td>    </tr></table>
```

Thanks

Comment: Show the final, generated HTML

Comment: your PHP code contains error . should be `echo '<td class="manu">'. $name['name'] . '</td>';`

Comment: Thanks I changed that but it did resolve the issue but did correct the table mistake thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did mistake in your css.
Check the *commented line* in below css..

*change **width:478;** to **width:478px;***

```
td.manu {
  background: url("../images/manu_button.fw.png") no-repeat; 
  height: 87px; 
  width:478;  /*------------------- add "px" after the value here--------------*/  
  /*----- 478px instead of only 478 ------*/
  font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; 
  color:#309;
  font-size:12px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that didn't make a difference, however i noticed another page had improved and so i think it is the following piece of code which is the problem :  echo '<td class="manu">'. $name['name'];'</td>';

Comment: i did changes using firebug on your given page. and i just changed that width:478 to width:478px and it worked well. :) there was no need of padding actually. one advise. Do not write unnecessary code if not needed.

Comment: @StanWilliams Right now your code is working because your `<a>` tag's css is overwriting `td.manu` class with `.manu a` class. It also contains `width:478px`. if you will remove **px** from there. your page will be same as before. Thank you. Enjoy :)

Comment: Sorry thanks, got it, i thought i had added the px, but i think i might of added it to another class, much appreciated and thanks for the advice.

Comment: @StanWilliams - Thats Fine !! NJoi ! ;)

Answer (score 1):

```
td.manu 
{
background: url("../images/manu_button.fw.png") no-repeat; 
height: 87px; 
width:478;  
font-family:Arial,Helvetica, sans-serif; 
color:#309;
font-size:12px;
padding-left:23px;
}

.manu a
    { 
       padding-left: 0;
    }
```

and

Change Table Width

```
<table width="907px" border="0">
      <!-- put Code here -->
</table>
```